# Помогите с массивами Delphi

Tags: массивы, delphi

Заданы координаты футболистов двух команд на поле, `i`-й футболист дает пас `j`-му.
Определить, имеет ли положение вне игры (оффсайд), если ворота атакующей команды находятся справа (слева).

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
type
  x = array [0..90] of Integer;
var
  i,j: Integer;

uses
  SysUtils;

begin
  randomize();
  for i:=1 to 90 do
    x[i]:=trunc(random(90));
  Randomize();
  for j:=1 to 90 do
    x[j]:=Random(90);
```

Я задал координаты для `i`-го и `j`-го игроков.
Как мне сравнить их координаты с координатами всех игроков другой команды (кроме вратаря) с условием что, если `j` находится правее (левее) их всех, тогда проверяете так же `i`-игрока - если он не правее (левее) всех противников, то - оффсайд.

Comment: эта задача для языка делфи.

Comment: за координаты принял длину поля

Comment: "координаты футболистов **двух** команд" - как минимум, Вам нужны **два** массива

Answer (score 0):

```
program offside;
type
  TTeam = array[1..10] of integer;
var
  fcReal, fcCSKA: TTeam;
  player: integer;
  lmin, lmax, rmin, rmax: integer;
begin
  Randomize;

  for player := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    fcReal[player] := Random(90); // позиция на поле
    fcCSKA[player] := Random(90);
  end;

  // fcReal - слева, fcCSKA - справа
  lmin := fcReal[1];
  lmax := fcReal[1];
  rmin := fcCSKA[1];
  rmax := fcCSKA[1];

  // находим крайних левых и правых игроков каждой команды
  for player := 2 to 10 do
  begin
    if (fcReal[player] < lmin) then
      lmin := fcReal[player];
    if (fcReal[player] > lmax) then
      lmax := fcReal[player];
    if (fcCSKA[player] < rmin) then
      rmin := fcCSKA[player];
    if (fcCSKA[player] > rmax) then
      rmax := fcCSKA[player];
  end;

  // если в атаке fcCSKA
  if (rmin < lmin) then
    writeln('Крайний левый игрок ЦСКА в оффсайде');
  // если в атаке fcReal
  if (rmax < lmax) then
    writeln('Крайний правый игрок Реала в оффсайде');
end.
```